# How to make Facebook apps setting in FB and multiple invite friend request

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, invitation

Working with C#(asp.net), m looking to develop to a fb application,i have made some setting in my fb apps but unable to redirect to my website page.

Here are the settting :-

```
App ID/API Key =XXXX
App Secret =XXXX
Site URL=http://localhost:1045/
Canvas URL=http://apps.facebook.com/XXXXXX/
Secure Canvas URL :- https://apps.facebook.com/kuwaitsoccer/
Canvas FBML/iframe :-iframe`enter code here`
Sandbox Mode :-Sandbox Mode
Contact Email =XXXX
Support Email=XXX
```

Please guide me what setting i have missed such that I'm unable to render my application. Facing page not found error.

Also please guide me how to add create "multi friend" invitation feature in iframe.

Answer (score 0):

check the follwing

1. Check application is running outside Facbook i.e., with fbintegration.
2. Change the Canvas url to your domain(http://localhost:xxx/)
3. Under App settings you grant access token and retry.